# Solution failed validation

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-365, sandbox-solution

I am creating an application for office 365.

My sandbox solution works fine in local system.
And it was working fine for office 365 site.

But suddenly it has stopped working and after that during adding any new sandbox web-part I am getting the same error of "Solution failed validation.".

It is generating same error for simple(only "hello" written) web-part also.

I have tried all the ways of adding that wsp again in solution gallery and deleting that web-part from Web-parts but it is not working.

Can anyone give me the solution..?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sand boxed solutions containing server side code has been deprecated since SP 2013. It could possibly be so that it is now disabled in O 365

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was due to more usage of resources. So increase your number of resources from admin site.